# At the beginning of an Ubuntu installation, what means the ”keyboard = human“ symbol?

Tags: installation, keyboard, accessibility

At the very beginning of the booting of an installation media (typically a USB stick), before even choosing your language, there is an intriguing symbol. It represents a keyboard, an equal sign (=) and a circled human. This circled human is similar to the accessibility symbol in GNOME.

What does the symbol mean and what would happen if I press a key at that time?

Comment: I think it means something like "press any key to access special options". If you don't press any key it boots as you selected "Install Ubuntu". If you press any key you get many other options (boot a live session, change language/keyboard, pass options to kernel/installer, etc)

Answer (score 5):

Enables the onscreen keyboard, for kiosks, and for keyboard connection failures.